# R: multiple 'method' arguments in call

Tags: r

I have a problem with several packages that include functions that need to be passed several named 'method' arguments, one for the original function call and one as part of the ellipsis '...' argument. 
Specifically, I am trying to fit an ordered probit model through ordinary maximum likelihood, but I want to apply bounds to the parameter estimates. I have the same problem with the relevant function in MASS and in the 'ordinal' package. I will illustrate it in MASS.

This is the function in MASS:

```
polr(formula, data, weights, start, ..., subset, na.action,
     contrasts = NULL, Hess = FALSE, model = TRUE,
     method = c("logistic", "probit", "loglog", "cloglog", "cauchit"))
```

polr calls the 'optim' function, and it allows to control aspects of the optimization by passing arguments to optim at the ellipsis. This is the function declaration of optim:

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

In order to have bounded optimization, I need to pass 'L-BFGS-B' to optim's 'method' argument (as well as 'lower' and 'upper' arguments). I would pass it as an ellipsis argument to 'polr', but then of course, 'polr' has its own 'method' argument, which, for my purposes, I should set to 'probit'.
Of course, passing 'method' twice in polr won't work. I am aware of the trick using incomplete argument names (ex 'metho') but it did not work for me. It cannot be passed as a 'control' list. In the 'ordinal' package, the method arguments are one level deeper, but the result is the identical dilemma. So what would work?

Here is a sample code that will reproduce the problem:

```
require(MASS)
x <- c(rep(0,6),rep(1,6))
resp <- as.factor(rep(seq(1,6),2))
Freq <- c(7,11,2,0,0,0,2,0,1,3,1,3)
# no problem:
polr(resp ~ x, weights= Freq, method = 'probit')
# but this is what I need (but can't):
polr(resp ~ x, weights = Freq, 
     # ellipsis arguments to pass to optim:
     method = 'L-BFGS-B', lower = rep(-5,6), upper = rep(5,6), 
     # necessary argument to polr:
     method='probit')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The line `optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...)` is hard coded into `polr.fit` which is called by `polr`. There is no option to change the method. You'd basically have to copy the code into your own versions of the functions to change that value.